# Unable to access files from UNC path in ASP.MVC aplpication hosted in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, unc

I'm downloading files from UNC path it is working fine on local host but when hosted on IIS 7 it gives me following error:
[image]

My Action in MVC that returns file is:

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public FileResult GetFile()
    {
            Request.ValidateInput();
            string fileLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UNCPath"];
            string fileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["fileName"]);
            string path = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileName);
            string getFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            string contentType = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(getFileExtension);
            return File(path, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

In Web confing I have UNCPath like \network\drivef...

Comment: you can get file if you past result `path` to your browser?

Comment: I mean do it on your server where IIS 7 located? Are you sure that you have right valid path at the end?

Comment: yes path is valid, if i put that in url then it gives me that file.

Comment: as it is running in local end , do i need to put some settings on IIS

Comment: than can you check under witch user ApplicationPool in IIS running? Does this user have permissions to your UNC folder?

Comment: @teovankot can you please tell me how to give permission to UNC folder.